# Язык C, сокрытие определения структур

Tags: c, struct, модули

Подскажите, как в **языке C** принято скрывать вспомогательные структуры внутри их модулей, чтобы они были видны только там?

Например, есть модуль **module**:

**module.h:**

```
struct global_s{...};// Структура известна всем, кто подключит module.h
```

**module.c:**

```
struct local_s{...};// Структура известна только внутри module.c
```

Так делать правильно?

Просто помнится был неприятный случай, когда забыли добавить объявление функции в *h* файл модуля, в результате чего при вызовах функции компилятор не сообщал об ошибке, а **каждый раз** вызвал функцию с неизвестными аргументами, в результате чего возникло неопределенное поведение, причину которого было очень сложно понять и отловить тестами.

Не произойдет ли такого "бага" с определением структуры, которое будет не в *h* файле, а в *c*?

Answer (score 0):

вопрос задавали на английском форуме, вот ссылка - [где ссылка?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368028/how-to-make-struct-members-private)

но если коротко

В  .h файле:

```
typedef struct point point;
```

В  .c файле:

```
struct point
{
    void *data;
};
```

Comment: А какие минусы есть у описанного мною способа?

Comment: минусов нет и все будет работать, я лишь передал способ через загаловочный файл однако в этом случае будут некие нюансы с аллокацией можете на англоязычном форуме прочитать (ссылку что я оставил)

Comment: Я почитал про нюансы с аллокацией на стеке - что-то не очень понял, с чем они связаны.

Comment: просто защита таким образом и осуществляется я если честно сам бы сделал как и вы в начале хотели в .с файле, просто видел этот вариант и передал его вам :) а можно узнать зачем код на с если вам нужна такая защита ? в с++ это гораздо профитнее или вы работаете с embedded системой?

Comment: Я так понял, что @Максим хочет скрыть не членов структуры, а всю структуру

Comment: Не ясно, как этот ответ относится к заданному вопросу. В вопросе речь идет совершенно о другом.

Comment: Работаю с embedded, да. Но даже если пишу не для встраиваемых систем, то у меня нет ни малейшего желания писать на C++. Я несколько лет поработал с C++(11), это такая боль, что я теперь как тот старый вояка из фильмов - каждый вечер прокручиваю в голове все свои прошлые страдания, которые испытывал при разработке на C++... Как-то так)

Comment: Я просто интересовался, как принято прятать структуру, если она используется в модуле A и при этом ее не должно быть видно из тех модулей, в которых используется модуль A. В общем, довольно неплохое решение, это описывать структуру в B.h и инклюдить в A.c, но не в A.h.

Comment: Если определить структуру в *.c, а затем назначить ей синоним в *.h, то ситуация получается интересная. С одной стороны - синоним структуры будет виден всем, кто подключит соответствующий заголовочный файл, а с другой - вы не сможете использовать этот синоним нигде, кроме *.c файла, в котором описана структура этого синонима...

Comment: @Максим собственно что вам и надо было :)  А насчет спп не знаю , на вкус и цвет :)